# How to Obx in RxStatus.success() function

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx, flutter-widget

I use CheckboxListTile to input checkbox.

this is a function to retrieve a list of data from firestore

```
  void initDoctorCategory() {
    DoctorCategoryService().getListDoctorCategory().then((doctorCategory) {
      change(doctorCategory, status: RxStatus.success());
    });
  }
```

And this is my widget. i cant using obx for update value in doctorCategory[index].value:

```
body: controller.obx(
        (doctorCategory) => Container(
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: doctorCategory!.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return Obx(() => CheckboxListTile(
                    title: Text(doctorCategory[index].categoryName!),
                    value: doctorCategory[index].value,
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      doctorCategory[index].value = value!;
                      // Get.back();
                    },
                  ));
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Im get the error:

> [Get] the improper use of a GetX has been detected.
> You should only use GetX or Obx for the specific widget that will be updated.
> If you are seeing this error, you probably did not insert any observable variables into GetX/Obx
> or insert them outside the scope that GetX considers suitable for an update
> (example: GetX => HeavyWidget => variableObservable).
> If you need to update a parent widget and a child widget, wrap each one in an Obx/GetX.
> """

How to solved this?
How to using Getx in RxStatus.success()?

Comment: Remove Obx from CheckboxListTile and also remove controller.obx(
        (doctorCategory). Just wrap your Container or  ListView.builder with Obx.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   body: Container(
    child: Obx(() {
      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: doctorCategory!.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return CheckboxListTile(
            title: Text(doctorCategory[index].categoryName!),
            value: doctorCategory[index].value,
            onChanged: (value) {
              doctorCategory[index].value = value!;
            },
          );
        },
      );
    }),
  ),
```

Be sure that you have Get.put or Get.lazyPut of your controller